# Google Sheets: How Do I Colour A Cell In 2 Cases Context Based on Values From Another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a heads up display on the number of Hints a user has collected in a contest.
There are different categories of hints here.

[image]

So I'm trying to create a process such that in the respective Hints tab (ie Bonus Hint in this case)
[image]

Filling in Column B (with the hint description), renders that Hint as being "obtained" and hence showing up "Green" in my Hints Overview sheet.

[image]

However, for "unobtained" hints, by not filling in Column B, I want my Hints Overview to instead **still show** the Hint number but in light gray (as illustrated below)
[image]

I dont want the unobtained hints to be empty cells. I want to make them looked grayed out. ^^^

I tried pulling some conditional formatting tricks like indirect(), ISBLANK() but something about CF just doesn't allow me to get what I desire.

And the other challenge is that because I arranged my headsup-display to be grid-like, the cell filling has to take on horizontal filling. Its not like as I can simply drag and fill 250 rows vertically.

How can I pull these things off in Google Sheets? (trust you guys to please dont maliciously edit my sheet out of mischief)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IG6l0xkJSU-mxP6YVr73RwinEcdxSePI4HN02KF-WoA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bLmL6E0odCB4aKBBZWqUeoyEYxKphmInL9wS6lsKQr8/edit?usp=sharing

 I have another Google Sheet that has the same dashboard but instead, this sheet aims to sort hints by Category. Each sheet will have rows allocated to store both Bonus and Golden Hints (and I have 8 of them). Still aiming for same behaviour of highlighting cell once the user keys in the hint number in Col B. Are we still able to use CF to loop thru all 8 sheets, identify the hint # in the approriate range and the highlight the cell? Or is this now too complex for CF ?

Answer (score 1):

delete everything in **`DASHBOARD!D8:AB17`**

use this in D8:

```
=SEQUENCE(10, 25)
```

remove your green CF rule and set the font to gray

[image]

now add this new CF rule as custom formula:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(D8, {ROW(INDIRECT("BONUS!B2:B"))-1, INDIRECT("BONUS!B2:B")}, 2, 0))<>""
```

and set background to your green and font to white

[image]

---

also change **`DASHBOARD!AD17`** to:

```
=COUNTA(BONUS!B2:B251)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Now i would like to enquire some deeper clarity in your code so that I can improvise on similar approaches in future time to come.

=INDEX(VLOOKUP(D8, {ROW(INDIRECT("BONUS!B2:B"))-1, INDIRECT("BONUS!B2:B")}, 2, 0))<>""

{ROW(INDIRECT("BONUS!B2:B"))-1, INDIRECT("BONUS!B2:B") : Multiple ranges in VLOOKUP. How does this multiple range address / detect that filling in Col B triggers the conditional formatting of the cell? I also played around  {ROW(INDIRECT("BONUS!A2:A"), INDIRECT("BONUS!B2:B") but the same behaviour couldnt be obtained.

Comment: @Ethan777 not sure what exactly are you asking but this is how it works: to control CF from other sheet we need ranges to be INDIRECTed. next, if you go to your bonus sheet you can see that your hints starts from row 2 but sequence starts from 1 to 250 so what we do is we subtract 1 to offset the "rows" where those hints are. so row 2 on bonus sheet "becomes" row 1 so now we can pair it in array {} with B column and use simple VLOOKUP where we check all cells of D8:AB17 but given the nature how CF works if we do not lock it with $

Comment: @Ethan777 the CF will loop automatically so we only use starting point which is D8 and we return 2nd column from our {} array (which is column B) only if there is an exact match  - thats the meaning of 0 in vlookup. so after vlookup we just check if vlookup returned something or nothing eg we CF the cell if vlookup is not empty  <>""

Comment: @Ethan777 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qwfs5CkOjLGDqYWFbLOCQKb8OVSrUXrcIteQ_mPws3M/edit#gid=2131273973

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bLmL6E0odCB4aKBBZWqUeoyEYxKphmInL9wS6lsKQr8/edit?usp=sharing

I have another Google Sheet that has the same dashboard but instead, this sheet aims to sort hints by Category. Each sheet will have rows allocated to store both Bonus and Golden Hints (and I have 8 of them).

Still aiming for same behaviour of highlighting cell once the user keys in the hint number in Col B.

Are we still able to use CF to loop thru all 8 sheets, identify the hint # in the approriate range and the  highlight the cell?

Or is this now too complex for CF ?